# How to use flutter plugin with advanced customisation

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I imported a flutter plugin but would like more customisation, i would like to use code from flutter plugin directly for higher customisation is it good practice to do so, and how do i do it.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question and tell us which plugin are you referring to?

Comment: The plugin is flutter collapsible sidebar https://pub.dev/packages/collapsible_sidebar